# how to use an expression in a select clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

consider the following pseudp code

```
Expression<Func<E,Datetime?>> expr = 
    e => (e.d1 ?? e.Rel.d1) ?? e.d2;
var q = myContext.E_DbSet.Select(x => new someDeclaredType {
    Id = x.Id,
    V = expr
});
```

> => CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.DateTime?'

if I try with compile

```
Expression<Func<E,Datetime?>> expr = 
    (e => (e.d1 ?? e.Rel.d1) ?? e.d2).Compile();
var q = myContext.E_DbSet.Select(x => new someDeclaredType {
    Id = x.Id,
    V = expr(x)
});
```

> => NotSupportedException: node type 'Invoke' of LINQ expression is not suported in LINQ to Entities.

I read [Invoke an Expression in a Select statement - LINQ to Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348099/invoke-an-expression-in-a-select-statement-linq-to-entity-framework). But this is not my exact case. I need to include an existing expression into my select clause. This expression comes as the result of a function call. So I must use `expr` in my select clause.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Expression<Func<E,someDeclaredType>> expr = 
e => new someDeclaredType() 
{
    Id = e.Id, 
    V = (e.d1 ?? e.Rel.d1) ?? e.d2 
};
var q = myContext.E_DbSet.Select(expr);
```

Comment: the point is that `(e.d1 ?? e.Rel.d1) ?? e.d2` comes from a function call.

Comment: is there any query syntax equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way:

```
Expression<Func<E,Datetime?>> expr = 
    e => (e.d1 ?? e.Rel.d1) ?? e.d2;
Expression<Func<E,someDeclaredType>> sel = 
    x => new someDeclaredType {
        Id = x.Id,
        V = expr.Compile()(x)
    };
var q = myContext.E_DbSet.Select(sel.Compile());
```

another coding is (from @Anthony):

```
Expression<Func<E, someDeclaredType>> sel =
e => new someDeclaredType()
{
    Id = e.Id,
    V = expr.Compile()(e)
};
q = Files.Select(sel.Compile());
```

by the sample: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8B3O5Q)

Please not that the code is designed for linq to entities. It may fire exception in linq to object due to `Rel = null`.

Comment: just -1, no reason why? please help me

Comment: I think I figure out the -1 reason. It seems that the use of `compile` trigger the load of the complete `DbSet` in memory.